# NLog exception as data object

Tags: c#, exception, nlog

I'm using NLog for logging exceptions to different targets.

One of the targets displays an execption window (like visual studio).
To do so I need the non rendered data of the exception. 
How should I setup the Layout for the target?

I have this to diassamble the exception to string:

```
[EXCEPTION]${exception:format=toString,Data:maxInnerExceptionLevel=10}
```

How to specify this to get the raw (serialized) data of the excepion ?

Answer (score 2):

The custom target should look at this property:

[LogEventInfo.Exception](http://nlog-project.org/documentation/v4.0.0/html/P_NLog_LogEventInfo_Exception.htm)

Comment: Hi, I'm currently using memory target as standard target. Do you mean I need to create a new target ? If yes, do you have an example ?

Comment: @BramVanDenBossche Very easy to google "custom nlog target", but now I have done it for you: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-write-a-custom-target

Comment: Thank you very much. I will create a custom target.